# How do you show your Outlook web add-in as a command bar item?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am writing an Outlook add-in and have noticed other add-in appear more prominently in the toolbar alongside the "reply, reply all" etc buttons. (See screenshot).
I can't find any documentation on how to achieve this, or is this just something that happens if you publish your add-in to Appsource?

[image]

Comment: Does it come from any COM based add-in?

Comment: Not sure whether that other add-in (hubspot) is a COM one or not.

Comment: COM add-ins have nothing to do with web add-ins and will not appear in any way in Outlook for Web. The icon you are observing from Web-based Outlook add-in.

Answer (score 0):

The placement and the order of Outlook Web Add-ins cannot be specified. This is up to the vendor (Microsoft) how, where and in which order the add-ins will be displayed in a particular application (Web interface, Outlook for Mac or Outlook desktop for Windows.). As the developer, you cannot specify the position of the launching icon for your add-on.

For example, Outlook Web Interface allows end-user to "pin" the icon on the same level as "reply... etc." buttons are for easy access for most used add-ons. The user is able to do this when installing add-in. See the provided screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the placement of the icon for launching the add-in?

Comment: @user8174007 Yes the placement of the icon. Is this what you asked for?